# cannot start virtual machine windows 8 hyper-v laptop i5

Tags: windows, windows-8, virtualization, hyper-v

I recently bought an Asus laptop equipped with i5-3317u 1.70GHz and Windows 8.
Upgraded to Windows 8 Pro and added the hyper-v feature.

Creating a VM goes OK but trying to start it, it fails with a message "could not initialize" and event id 3040.

I have searched all over and can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Did you verify that Virtualization is activated in bios? Did you restart your computer after installing the hyper-v feature? Check this microsoft article on the subject: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd581971(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: verified the bios settings and restarted after adding the hyper-v feature.
I don't understand this MS article:
1. it relates to Win 2008 rather than Win 8
2. access? the service runs under the localservice account. this should be sufficient, right?

Comment: Regardless of windows version, the feature/application throws the same error(3040). Could you start the event viewer and post the full hyper-v error here? You could also try unistalling hyper-v and install the application VMware Player(freeware) just to check that your virtualization works at all.

Comment: I tried removing hyper-v, installed VMware player. result: VMware player works.  After that I removed VMware player and reinstalled Hyper-V and I get the same error:
'New Virtual Machine2' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID DE5F9FC4-6A82-4039-85E3-18A82A938FEE)
Log name: Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker/Admin
Source: Hyper-V-Worker
Event ID: 3040

Comment: Try setting up a new user with admin rights, and set up a new machine from that account. Report back after that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 8.1 Pro and this error came long with zero effective fixes.
Finally I came across this:

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/379549-hyper-v-2012-vm-s-wont-initialize-no-other-error-msg?page=1#entry-4515524

The fix:

From an elevated command prompt:

net localgroup administrators LOCAL /delete

net localgroup administrators SERVICE /delete

Afterwards, you'll get a "could not create or access saved state file" error along with the initialize error. When trying to run a VM.

Note the VM ID, goto C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines and in the folder with the same name as the VM ID, delete the .bin and .vsv file.  - No VM's should be running at this point.

Launching the VM you'll see that your VM will be back up.

In my case, Hyper-V had been running fine all along and then after month or two of it not being used, I got the inexplicable error.  This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Same error, Same disappointing "Fixes". I found that the system created a virtual drive in a location that required elevation to access. I created a new virtual drive under my profile and afterwards had a successful start

Comment: this looks like a a comment than an answer...